# Solving a matrix equation of form: $AA^T=B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, quadratics, matrix-equations

Given
$$AA^T=B$$ So if $A$ is a vector of size $(m,1)$, then $A^T$ is of size $(1,m)$. Producing $B$  (square matrix) $(m,m)$. Now my question is, I know the value of the matrix $B$. Is there a way, that I can solve the above equation to obtain $A$.

Comment: I think you mean "size" instead of "rank," which has a very different meaning in linear algebra. Note that the diagonal elements of $B$ are equal to the squares of the elements of $A$, so that should get you started.

Comment: ok, thanks I edited the rank, and also thanks for the hint, let me go back to my calculations, i will keep you updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess one way is to let $A_{(m\times 1)}=\left(\begin{matrix}a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_m\end{matrix}\right)$.

\begin{align}
A_{(m\times 1)}A^{T}_{(1\times m)} & = \left(\begin{matrix}a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_m\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}a_1 \ \cdots \ a_m\end{matrix}\right) \\
& = \left(\begin{matrix}a_1^2 \ \ \ a_1a_2 \  \ \ a_1a_3 \ \cdots \ a_1a_m \\
a_2a_1 \ \ \ a_2^2 \ \ a_2a_3 \ \cdots \ a_2a_m \\
\vdots \\
a_ma_1 \ \ a_ma_2 \ \ a_ma_3 \ \cdots \ a_m^2\\
\end{matrix}\right) \\
\end{align}
Now equate corresponding entries in $B$ to solve for $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_m$.

Answer (score 2):

If $B$ is $0$, then $A$ is the zero vector.

Suppose not, we know $B$ is symmetric and rank $1$ if such decomposition exists.

Since it is symmetric, you can just compute its eigenvalue decomposition.

Suppose the eigenvalue is $\lambda \ne 0$ and the corresponding eigenvector $v$.

Then we have $$B=\lambda vv^T=(\sqrt{\lambda}v)(\sqrt{\lambda}v^T)$$

Comment: +1, this clearly gives non-uniqueness as well